# Codeigniter unable to load the requested file in a mobile device

Tags: php, iphone, codeigniter

I am getting a `Unable to load the requested file: default.php` error in codeigniter whenever i load up the website in a mobile device. It loads perfectly in desktop browser.

here is how my controller is set up,

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->template->set_layout('default')->build('welcome_en');
    }

}
```

Default is Sparks template i am using for the current template i am using for the "welcome_en" view page.

I have been trying to figure out this problem for a while now, there is no user agent detection script being used, there was before but i took it out in hopes of getting rid of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to create web and mobile folder. [More info](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/mobile.html)

Instead of `application/views/layouts/default.php` try `application/views/web/layouts/default.php` and `application/views/mobile/layouts/default.php`.

Same for all your other layout files, they will load the mobile version if you browse to the page with anything CodeIgniter thinks is a mobile phone (not an iPad).

Comment: Yes that worked, i had the mobile dir, just not a web dir and i guess that's where codeigniter was getting mixed up, thank you so much, been stuck in this problem for a while.